# The Form Validation is not working (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I did my form validation first and it worked.However, after i include my other functions in my javascript file, it stops working. I try to check all the functions but i couldnt find where did i do wrong. Im still new to javascript so thank you in advance for those that took their time to fix my problem.

```
var gErrorMsg = "";

function validateForm() {
    "use strict";
    var isAllOK = false;
    gErrorMsg = "";
    var fnameOK = FName();
    var lnameOK = LName();
    var emailOK = Email();
    var addOK = Address()
    var cityOk = City();
    var pnOK = PN();


    if (fnameOK && lnameOK && emailOK && addOK && cityOk && pnOK) {
        isAllOK = true;
    }
    else {
        alert(gErrorMsg);
        gErrorMsg = "";
        isAllOK = false;
    }

    return isAllOK;
}

function FName() {
    var owner = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
    var nameOk = true;
    if ((owner.length == 0)) {
        gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Your first name cannot blank**\n"
        nameOk = false;
    }
    else {
        if (!pattern.test(owner)) {
            gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Your first name must only contain alpha characters**\n"
            nameOk = false;
        }
    }

    return nameOk;
}

function LName() {
    var owner = document.getElementById("Lname").value;
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
    var nameOk = true;
    if ((owner.length == 0)) {
        gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Your last name cannot blank**\n"
        nameOk = false;
    }
    else {
        if (!pattern.test(owner)) {
            gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Your last name must only contain alpha characters**\n"
            nameOk = false;
        }
    }

    return nameOk;
}

function Email() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var result = false;
    var pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-za-zA-Z0-9.-]{1,4}$/;
    if (pattern.test(email.value)) {
        result = true;
    }
    else {  //braces a good idea even if not strictly needed for single statement
        result = false;
        gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Enter a valid email address **\n"
    }
    return result;
}

function Address() {
    var add = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var addOk = true;
    if ((add.length == 0)) {
        gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Your address cannot blank**\n"
        addOk = false;
    }

    return addOk;
}

function City() {
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
    var cityOk = true;
    if ((city.length == 0)) {
        gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Please state the city you are form**\n"
        cityOk = false;
    }
    else {
        if (!pattern.test(city)) {
            gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Your city name must only contain alpha characters**\n"
            cityOk = false;
        }
    }

    return cityOk;
}

function PN() {
    var pn = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var pnOk = true;
    var pattern = /^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$/g;
    if ((pn.length == 0)) {
        gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Please state your contact number**\n"
        pnOk = false;
    }
    else {
        if (!pattern.test(pn)) {
            gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Your contact number should only has 10 numbers*\n"
            pnOk = false;
        }
    }

    return pnOk;
}

function storeitem(item_id) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("item_id", item_id);
    window.location.replace("enquiry.html");
}
function displayitem() {
    document.getElementById("sbj").value = "RE: Enquiry on " + sessionStorage.getItem("item_id");
}








function validateForm() {
    var product = document.getElementById("type").value;
    sessionStorage.product = product;

    return result;
}

//Store individual product page into sessionStorage
function storeProduct(productName) {
    var options = ["Runway", "Commercial", "Fitness", "Fashion"];

    options.forEach(array);

    function array(value) {
        if (value == productName) {
            sessionStorage.productIndex = options.indexOf(value);
        }
    }
}

//Fill the subject field with the value of product
function storeSub() {
    document.getElementById("type").selectedIndex = sessionStorage.productIndex;

    var product = document.getElementById("type").value;

    sessionStorage.subject = product;
    document.getElementById("subject").value = sessionStorage.subject;
}

//Storing first optgroup into array

function productlist1() {
    var select = document.getElementById("type");

    var options = ["Runway", "Commercial", "Fitness", "Fashion"];

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}

//change the value of the session storage according to the new product selected by user

function change() {
    var product = document.getElementById("type").value;
    sessionStorage.product = product;
    document.getElementById("subject").value = sessionStorage.product;
}






//if validateForm returns returns false nothing will be sent to the server
function init() {
    var regForm = document.getElementById("form");

    //Lecture 7  - following 2 calls register inputs elements to respond to onblur and onclick events.
    //registerInputsOnBlur();
    //registerInputsOnClick();
    regForm.onsubmit = validateForm;
    displayitem()
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: What's with the sessionStorage.something = something? You need getItem and setItem and if it is not a string you need to JSON.stringify to save and JSON.parse to read

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you get any error? Until what point does it still work?

Comment: Use OOP(Object Oriented Programming) to have clean code and more readable handwriting in coding